# Add/Edit multiple Records on custom VF page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Is it possible to add or edit multiple records on a custom VF page? For the example below, if lineItemList return fewer than 10 records, I would like to render blank inputfields for insert of new records. The way I have it set now, it will only render as many inputfields as existing records. As always, any help is appreciated.

**Page:**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Resourcing_Plan__c" extensions="MultipleLineItemsController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:outputField value="{!rp.name}"/>
                <apex:pageblocktable>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!lineItemList}" var="a">
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Resource_type__c}" /></td>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Weekly_commitment_fte__c}"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Area_of_Expertise__c }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageblocktable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class MultipleLineItemsController 
{
    public resourcing_plan__c rp {get;set;}
    public list<Resource_plan_line_item__c> lineItemList{get;set;}
    public MultipleLineItemsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        controller.addFields(New String[]{'name'});
        rp= (Resourcing_Plan__c)controller.getRecord();
        lineItemList=[select Resource_type__c, Weekly_commitment_fte__c, 
            Area_of_Expertise__c from Resource_plan_line_item__c where 
            Resourcing_Plan__c=:rp.id limit 10];    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example similar to what you are trying, you can run the below standalone files and find the logic. You can implement the same logic in your code.

**VF Page (addcontactpage)**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AddContacts" sidebar="false">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts" id="pb">
      <apex:pageMessages />      
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable" title="Contacts" var="acc" value="{!contactList}">
          <apex:column headerValue="No." style="width:20px; text-align:center;" headerClass="centertext">
            <apex:outputText value="{0}" style="text-align:center;">
              <apex:param value="{!rowNumber+1}" />
            </apex:outputText>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="First Name" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.FirstName}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.LastName}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="pb">
              <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Contact" reRender="pb"/>      
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>           
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class AddContacts {
        public Account accounts;
        public Contact del;
        public List < Contact > addContactList {get;set;}
        public List < Contact > delContactList {get;set;}
        public List < Contact > contactList {get;set;}
        public Integer totalCount {get;set;}
        public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}
        public List < Contact > delContacts {get;set;}

        public AddContacts(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
                accounts = (Account) controller.getRecord();
                contactList = [Select id, firstName, LastName from Contact where AccountId = : accounts.Id];
                totalCount = contactList.size();
                delContactList = new List < Contact > ();
                delContacts = new List < Contact > ();
        }

        public void addRow() {
                addContactList = new List < Contact > ();
                contactList.add(new Contact(AccountId = accounts.Id));
        }

        public PageReference save() {
                upsert contactList;
                delete delContactList;
                //return (new ApexPages.StandardController(accounts)).view();
                PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/addcontactpage');
                pageRef.getParameters().put('id',accounts.Id);
                return pageRef;
        }
        public void deleteRow() {
                rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
                del = contactList.remove(rowIndex);
                delContactList.add(del);
        }
}
```